# Web project not deploying in eclipse server

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, web

I have a problem with deploy of `web application` to the server locally eclipse.

I imported a new project to the workspace. It is maven project, so updated all dependencies, snapshots and releases. The project has properties set `Dynamic Web Module 3.1`, `Java 8` and even selected runtime server.
Then I add it to the server and run the server problem is that project is added "empty" nothing is deployed. To say the truth I have no idea where can be problem/mistake.

Here is image, hot it looks like in eclipse:
[image]

Would appreciate if someone can give me any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to right-click on your project and select Maven --> Update Project?

This will import your Maven project setup to eclipse. After trying this out, restart the application server and tell us if that worked.